# Spring social facebook and twitter access

Tags: spring, spring-social

I downloaded an Spring Social facebook application using the link:  https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-facebook

I downloaded an Spring Social twitter application using the link: 
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-twitter

I am confused with `ConnectController`. It is using Spring Boot for deploying the application but in the console:

```
 Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
```

I am trying to access user facebook data through this application. So when I run the application with:

```
http://localhost:8080/connect/twitter
```

then I click Connect To Twitter. The address gets changed to:

```
http://localhost:8080/connect/twitter;jsessionid=5D2034AFF69C8A5F8F1A76B69D091BF1
```

it stays on the same page and doesn't go to the next page i.e.

```
hello.html
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you think the path variable `{providerId}` is for. Instead of making things up you might want to read the spring social reference guide. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#creating-connections-with-connectcontroller

Comment: Okay. So when I run the application it just get refreshed with "jsessionid=5D2034AFF69C8A5F8F1A76B69D091BF1" is appended. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please explain what you want/try because currently it is totally unclear wat you want. Your comment isn't really helping either. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.